# select2 initSelection for redisplayed the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2, select2-rails

I'm Using Select2-rails '3.5.3, I can do search with remote data and save it, the problem is how I can restore the selected text (for example if user press edit), problem: initSelection is not fired when form loaded with edit

below is my code

**hotelcheck.coffee**

```
  $('.select2-autocomplete').each (i, e) ->
  select = $(e)
  options = { 
    multiple: false
    width: "98%"
    placeholder: "Type Hotel name"
    minimumInputLength: 3
  }
  options.ajax =
    url: select.data('source')
    dataType: 'json'
    type: "GET"
    quietMillis: 250
    # input untuk program
    data: (term, page) ->
      { q: term, 
      page: page,
      per: 25 }
    results: (data) ->
      { results: $.map(data, (item) ->
        {
          text: item.name
          id: item.id
        }
      ) }
    initSelection: (element, callback) ->
      id = $(element).val()
      if id != ''
        $.ajax('/hotels/' + id + '.json', dataType: 'json').done (data) ->
          selected = 
            id: element.val()
            text: data.name
          callback selected
          return
      return
  options.dropdownCssClass = 'bigdrop'
  select.select2 options
```

form to show hidden field, I save the content to hotel_id

```
<%= f.hidden_field :hotel_id, data: { source: search_name_hotels_path }, class: "select2-autocomplete", :value => "#{f.object.hotel_id unless f.object.new_record? || f.object.hotel_id.nil? }" %>
```

**hotel controller for ajax send the value**

```
def show
  @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:id])
  puts "running fill name"

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @hotel }
  end
end
```

- source data = hotel table with field id, name
- client table = order with field hotel_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this page](http://select2.github.io/select2/#ajax), it looks like `initSelection` should NOT be in `options.ajax`, but just in `options`. I would try to copy the example they have and edit it to your needs. OR update to `4.0.0`, which seems to be much easier.

Comment: yes, you right I just moved initselection under options and it's work, many thanks